# Парсинг UTC Time в JSON.net

Tags: c#, json, парсер, datetime, json.net

не получается сериализация json-string в свой entity-class.
есть такой json с временем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот так выглядит мой SerializerClass и его настройки.Но как видно на скриншоте, в entity у меня все по нулям. сама property в классе DataTime (пробовал и DateTimeOffset и string) 
я уже все настройки перепробовал и даже стринг, но он, к моему удивлению, был равен null.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста что я проглядел.
P.S: Кому интересно вот API [Here-Api](https://weather.cit.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=observation&latitude=54.312791&longitude=10.175395&oneobservation=true&app_id=%7B%7BYOUR_APP_ID%7D%7D&app_code=%7B%7BYOUR_APP_CODE%7D%7D&language=de)

Comment: 1. Вы говорите про код, а объясняете все скринами. Код размещайте текстом! 2. Я не вижу у вас класса для сериализации/десериализации, где будут свойства `utcTime` и др, я вижу лишь абстракцию. 3. Ваш API бесполезен без авторизации (многие ее делать не буду), приложите наверно JSON текстом, что бы мы могли проверить у себя.

Comment: Ну и как бы, я без понятия что вы там за огород из кучи лишнего кода нагородили, обычная десериализация [справляется с поставленной зачей](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4wyNsS). Давайте нам самодостаточный пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду исправляться. 
А проблему решил. Перемудрил с настройками Json.Net. Убрал NamingStrategy и заработало.